# Semaphore equivalent in Node js , variable getting modified in concurrent request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I am facing this issue for the past 1 week and I am just confused about this.
Keeping it short and simple to explain the problem.

We have an in memory Model which stores values like budget etc.Now when a call is made to the API it has a spent associated with it.

We then check the in memory model and add the spent to the existing spend and then check to the budget and if it exceeds we donot accept any more clicks of that model. for each call we also udpate the db but that is a async operation.

A short example

```
api.get('/clk/:spent/:id', function(req, res) {
   checkbudget(spent, id);
}

checkbudget(spent, id){
  var obj =    in memory model[id]
  obj.spent+= spent;
  obj.spent > obj.budjet // if greater.
    obj.status = 11 // 11 is the stopped status
    update db and rebuild model. 
}
```

This used to work fine but now with concurrent requests we are getting false spends out spends increase more than budget and it stops after some time. We simulated the call with j meter and found this.

As far as we could find node is async so by the time the status is updated to 11 many threads have already updated the spent for the campaign.

How to have a semaphore kind of logic for Node.js so that the variable budget is in sync with the model

**update**

```
 db.addSpend(campaignId, spent, function(err, data) {
        campaign.spent += spent;
        var totalSpent = (+camp.spent) + (+camp.cpb);
        if (totalSpent  > camp.budget) {
            logger.info('Stopping it..');
            camp.status = 11; // in-memory stop
            var History = [];
            History.push(some data);
            db.stopCamp(campId, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error('Error while stopping );
                }
                model.campMAP = buildCatMap(model);
                model.campKeyMap = buildKeyMap(model);
                db.campEventHistory(cpcHistory, false, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error(Error);
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
```

GIST of the code can anyone help now please

Comment: `We then check the in memory model and add the spent to the existing spend` does this update the in memory model?

Comment: `update db and rebuild model.` so, you only rebuild model once status == 11? is the rebuild synchronous? or is it done once the DB is updated, asynchronously no doubt - really some REAL code would be far easier to answer

Comment: Yes this updated the model @JaromandaX

Comment: Yes only when it is 11 we update the db but we update the in memory model before updating the db, yes db call is async . Sorry i cannot share production code

Comment: so, you don't update the in memory model until `obj.spent > obj.budjet`? so, you could have 10000000 requests all where `spent` is less than `obj.budjet` and the in memory model is never updated? that's what it looks like from your fragmented pseudo code

Comment: Yes update model for each spent as i said but only put the status as 11 stopped when the spent has exceeded the budget

Comment: your pseudo code suggests otherwise

Comment: Yes that is the short version of the same

Comment: Doing a obj.status == 11 will in turn change the memory model too right ?

Comment: I don't know ... `rebuild model`, I assumed is the only time it updates -I simply can't guess what pseudo code is doing

Comment: rebuild model is nothing but we pull everything from database and sync the model as we had already put status as 11 after putting status we put the spend and id in the db

Comment: @JaromandaX any idea on this really need some help on this . how to handle concurrency in node ?

Comment: Concurrency, as in multi-threading or multi-process? You are aware that this would not solve your problem, but complicate it even more, right?

Comment: Read that : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern (Parallel Processing :  Where the commands are written as tasks to a shared resource and executed by many threads in parallel)

Comment: @mingos how to solve this issue any idea on this ?

Comment: @mingos i have upodated the gist of the actuall code where it happens

Comment: @JaromandaX i have upodated the gist of the actuall code where it happens

Answer (score 9):

**Q:** Is there `semaphore` or equivalent in `NodeJs`?

**A:** **No.**

**Q:** Then how do `NodeJs` users deal with race condition?

**A:** In theory you shouldn't have to as there is no `thread` in `javascript`.

Before going deeper into my proposed solution I think it is important for you to know how `NodeJs` works.

For `NodeJs` it is driven by an event based architecture. This means that in the `Node` process there is an event queue that contains all the "to-do" events.

When an `event` gets `pop` from the queue, `node` will execute **all** of the required code until it is finished. Any `async` calls that were made during the run were spawned as other `events` and they are queued up in the `event queue` until a response is heard back and it is time to run them again.

**Q:** So what can I do to ensure that only 1 request can perform `updates` to the database at a time?

**A:** I believe there are many ways you can achieve this but one of the easier way out is to use the `set_timeout` API.

**Example:**

```
api.get('/clk/:spent/:id', function(req, res) {
   var data = { 
       id: id
       spending: spent
   }
   canProceed(data, /*functions to exec after canProceed=*/ checkbudget);
}

var canProceed = function(data, next) {
    var model = in memory model[id];

    if (model.is_updating) {
        set_timeout(isUpdating(data, next), /*try again in=*/1000/*milliseconds*/);
    }
    else {
        // lock is released. Proceed.
        next(data.spending, data.id)
    }
}


checkbudget(spent, id){
  var obj =    in memory model[id]

  obj.is_updating = true; // Lock this model

  obj.spent+= spent;
  obj.spent > obj.budjet // if greater.
    obj.status = 11 // 11 is the stopped status
    update db and rebuild model. 
    obj.is_updating = false; // Unlock the model
}
```

**Note:** What I got here is pseudo code as well so you'll may have to tweak it a bit.

The idea here is to have a flag in your model to indicate whether a `HTTP request` can proceed to do the critical code path. In this case your `checkbudget` function and beyond.

When a request comes in it checks the `is_updating` flag to see if it can proceed. If it is `true` then it schedules an event, to be fired in a second later, this "setTimeout" basically becomes an event and gets placed into `node`'s event queue for later processing

When this event gets fired later, the checks again. This occurs until the `is_update` flag becomes `false` then the request goes on to do its stuff and `is_update` is set to false again when all the critical code is done.

Not the most efficient way but it gets the job done, you can always revisit the solution when performance becomes a problem.

Comment: thanks for the solution but performance is a key point in my application we are looking for through put of around 1 - 10 ms . and i dnt think this will work out ?

Comment: When we talk about `throughput` it is always about the amount of transactions it can process per amount of time. I suspect you meant response time here. If you are worried about the response time then tweak the `retry` time to be at `10ms`. Why not implement the solution and conduct stress test against it? Pretty sure it will work just fine. Otherwise feel free to raise your concern.

Comment: `is_updating` is a boolean acting as a semaphore here

Comment: @SamuelToh Okay so if NodeJs puts requests to queue. Then isn't it obvious that only 1 request is updating the database? Why would setTimeout would be used?

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer is terrible.

First of all, yes, there is a semaphore in Nodejs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore.

Second of all, their proposed solution is a spin lock (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) which is just about the worst solution possible for critical sections. Please just use a semaphore and not these weird nonstandard terrible coding practices. Just because nodejs runs on one process does NOT mean that there aren't critical sections and race conditions...